# epoch and calculating mean square error for training set Neural Network

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

My question is about Neural Network Training. I already searched about this but, there is no good explanation about it.

So for the first one, how to calculate mean square error? (I know this is silly, but I really don't get it)

second:
When Neural Network do its training , we inputted a Training Set which consists of many pairs(Input and its desired output). Now when should we calculate the mean square error? does it when we already take all pairs? or does we calculate it for each pair?

if it is for each pair, then there is possibility when the error reaches the minimum desired error before all pairs inside Training set taken.

third: does epoch value increase for one loop of training set? or does it increase when each pairs(input and desired output) taken?(I know this is another silliness but please bear with it)

thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> y question is about Neural Network Training. I already searched about this but, there is no good explanation about it.

There are dozens of good explanations on the web, and in the literature, one such example may be the book by Haykin: *Neural Networks and Learning machines*

> So for the first one, how to calculate mean square error? (I know this is silly, but I really don't get it)

In the most simple terms, mean squared error is defined as

```
sum_i 1/n (desired_output(i) - model_output(i))^2
```

So you simply calculate the **mean** of the **squares** of the **errors** (differences between your output, and the desired one).

> Now when should we calculate the mean square error? does it when we already take all pairs? or does we calculate it for each pair?

Both methods are used, one is called **batch** learning, and one is **online** learning. So all next questions have the answer "both are correct, depending whether you are using batch or online learning". Which one to choose? Obviously - it depends, but for a sake of simplicity I would suggest starting with **batch** learning (so you compute the error over **all** training samples and then update).

Comment: so error that is compared with specified minimum error when people say about the result error from the neural network training, is it the mean square error?or are there any type of error?

Comment: There are many types of errors, including mean squared error, entropy error, 0/1 loss, etc. it is also measured on different datasets: training data (unimportant measure), validation error (important measure from the point of training stopping) or testing data (important measure, showing the generalization error)

Answer (score 0):

If we train using online training and error reaches minimum value before all the data items in the training set are covered, then we skip the updation of weights for that value and continue to the next training data, i.e. we make sure that we complete an epoch before quitting training